# how to set default value of a reactjs select option and use that as intial state

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-state, streamlit

In my below code. I have initial state values (tag and value under public state) which are initially empty. These values currently changes based on the react select option (handlechange and handletagchange class) . But, i am also getting some input values from an upstream streamlit app and i want to use these values to set the initial values of state i.e for 'value' :(init_value) and 'tag' :(firsttag) - (please refer to variables after public render). Then later i want to change these default change based on the selection from the react select (handle change and handle tag change). Can some one help how to do that?

```
import {
  Streamlit,
  StreamlitComponentBase,
  withStreamlitConnection,
} from "streamlit-component-lib"
import React, { ReactNode } from "react"
import {TokenAnnotator, TextAnnotator} from 'react-text-annotate'
//import _ from 'lodash'
//import { Label } from 'semantic-ui-react'


const Card = ({children}:any) => (
  <div
    style={{
      boxShadow: '0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.1)',
      margin: 6,
      maxWidth: 500,
      padding: 16,
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </div>
)

/**
 * This is a React-based component template. The `render()` function is called
 * automatically when your component should be re-rendered.
 */

class NlpAnnotate extends StreamlitComponentBase {
  
  public state = {value: [], tag: ''}
 
  handleChange = (value:any) => {
    this.setState({value})
  }

  handleTagChange = (e:any) => {
    this.setState({tag: e.target.value})
  }
  
  public render = (): ReactNode => {
  
    const TEXT = this.props.args["text"]
    const options = this.props.args["options"]
    const init_value:any = []
    var first = options[0]
    const firsttag = first.value
    
    
    const TAG_COLORS:any = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {TAG_COLORS[options[i].label] = options[i].color;}
    
    return (
        <div style={{padding: 24, fontFamily: 'IBM Plex Sans'}}>
        <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', marginBottom: 24}}>
          <Card>
            <h4>Text for annotation</h4>
            <select onChange={this.handleTagChange} value={this.state.tag}>
                {options.map((option:any) => (
                <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
                ))}
            </select>
            <TextAnnotator
              style={{
                fontFamily: 'IBM Plex Sans',
                maxWidth: 500,
                lineHeight: 1.5,
              }}
              content={TEXT}
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              getSpan={(span:any) => ({
                ...span,
                tag: this.state.tag,
                color: TAG_COLORS[this.state.tag],
              })}
            />
          </Card>
        </div>
        
        <Card>
          <h4>Json String</h4>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify({TEXT},null,2)}</pre>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.value, null, 2)}</pre>
        </Card>
        <button
            onClick={() => Streamlit.setComponentValue(JSON.stringify(this.state.value, null, 2))}
        >
        save
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// "withStreamlitConnection" is a wrapper function. It bootstraps the
// connection between your component and the Streamlit app, and handles
// passing arguments from Python -> Component.
//
// You don't need to edit withStreamlitConnection (but you're welcome to!).
export default withStreamlitConnection(NlpAnnotate)
```

Comment: Where do these upstream values come in as for this component, props?

Comment: Upstream value comes as Args....as part of initial steps under public render

Comment: Ah, I see, so they are passed as props. What specific props (or args) are you wanting to update in local component state?

Comment: init_value and firsttag as state value value and tag respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it by changing the public state as follows: public state = {value: this.props.args["init_value"], tag: this.props.args.options?.[0]?.value}

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle component.

`init_value` just seems to be a local variable you declared in `render` and it's already equal to the `this.state.value` value and not used, but I see that `firsttag` is `this.props.args.options[0].value`.

```
public componentDidUpdate = (prevProps): void => {
  // check first tag
  if (
    prevProps.args.options?.[0]?.value !== this.props.args.options?.[0]?.value &&
    this.props.args.options?.[0]?.value
  ) {
    this.setState({
      tag: this.props.args.options[0].value,
    });
  }
  // other arg checks
};
```

### Update

Since it seems that Stramlit extends the [`React.PureComponent` class and overrides the `componentDidUpdate` method](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/blob/develop/component-lib/src/StreamlitReact.tsx#L51-L65) you might be need to work within the override's method signature and just access the `args` from the current props in scope.

```
public componentDidUpdate = (): void => {
  // After we're updated, tell Streamlit that our height may have changed.
  Streamlit.setFrameHeight();

  // Attempt to update state with first tag
  this.setState({
    tag: this.props.args.options?.[0]?.value,
  });
};
```

Comment: Let me try this script. I am going to change the code to pass Args for init_value from streamlit.

Comment: I am getting the following error when i run this script - "Property 'componentDidUpdate' in type 'NlpAnnotate' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'StreamlitComponentBase<{}>'.
  Type '(prevProps: any) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.  TS2416
"

Comment: @VinayKamisetty Ok, I has suspected this might occur but thought it might work anyway. Normally you don't extend the React `Component` or `PureComponent` classes, but instead compose over them. It seems that this Streamlit library's [`StreamlitComponentBase` extends `PureComponent`](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/blob/develop/component-lib/src/StreamlitReact.tsx#L51-L65) and overrides the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. The [docs](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/develop_streamlit_components.html#react) are quite sparse on working with React.

Comment: Hi understood. Thanks for your effort though. i am figuring out a way to resolve this and will keep you updated on the solution.

Comment: @VinayKamisetty I thought I had searched for a `streamlit` tag when I first started looking into this, and didn't see one, but searched again just now and it's there, so I added the `streamlit` tag and hopefully anyone watching it might see your question and provide assistance. From what I can tell, and know, this isn't *really* a React issue. I'll probably delete my answer soon (unless it's actually been helpful at all) you can ping (at) me in the main comment thread if you need me for anything further. Sorry, I tried to help.

Comment: I have resolved it by changing the public state as follows:  public state = {value: this.props.args["init_value"], tag: this.props.args.options?.[0]?.value}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support on this. How can i buy you a coffee.

Comment: @VinayKamisetty Ah, I see... I was assuming that the data you needed wasn't available on the initial render when the component was mounting. Sorry for any confusion I may've caused. Glad you have it sorted out.